# The right way to push changes to git

Tags: git

I've got two branches. First branch, let's call it `branch_A` is created from `master`. Several commits and pushes were there and after that I have created another branch `branch_B` from `branch_A`. Now, *after few pushes here*, I have realized that I need to fix something on `branch_A`, but I'll also need those changes on `branch_B`.

What would be the steps? Should I checkout `branch_A`, make those changes and push them, and after checkout `branch_B` and do a pull? Would it be `pull origin branch_A` or `pull origin branch_B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet pushed `branch_B`, then I suggest doing a rebase:

```
# from branch_B
git rebase branch_A
```

This will rewrite `branch_B` to bring in the latest changes from `branch_A`, including whatever fix you needed to make in the latter branch.  After the rebase is completed, `branch_B` will appear to have been created on top of a `branch_A` that never had the problem you fixed.

Note that after the rebase, you will have to force push the `branch_B`:

```
git push --force origin branch_B
```

The reason for the force push is that you have rewritten the history of that branch.

If `branch_B` has already been pushed *and* is shared by someone other than you, then cherry picking the fix commit might make the most sense:

```
# from branch_B
git cherry-pick abc123
```

Here, replace `abc123` with the commit hash from the fix you made in `branch_A`.

Comment: But I have, there are some pushes on `branch_B` also

Comment: Yes, it's only me